# Present perfect continuous instead of the present perfect BrE/AmE

Tags: present-perfect

I have been studying the difference between the present perfect continuous and the present perfect. I have read different opinions about these sentences:

> She **has been teaching** English for two years
> She **has taught** English for two years

According to some native speakers both are correct, but I also read that "She has taught English for two years" is unnatural and the present perfect continuous is a better option.

The same about "study;" I have read that the first is more natural:

> She **has been studying** English for two years
> She **has studied** English for two years

Should I consider both options as correct and use what most native speakers think is correct, which is  either the present perfect continuous or the present perfect with "study" and "teach"? Is this the difference between BrE and AmE?

Comment: This has been dealt with on this site in multiple questions. However, please note that the BrE/AmE issue is irrelevant here. The meanings of both forms are the same in both varieties of English. Both forms are correct; but they mean different things.

Comment: For example: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/182679/why-is-the-present-perfect-simple-used-in-this-sentence-and-not-the-present-per/182696#182696 //or//https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/161041/difference-between-present-perfect-simple-or-continuous/161063#161063

Comment: Don't they mean the same in present perfect and progressive that the person is still teaching and studying with "for"? 1. "She has been teaching English for two years. 
2. "She has taught English for two years." 3. "She has been studying English for two years."
4  "She has studied English for two years".

Comment: Antonia, they do not mean the same thing. Go **back** and reread my examples. And **then you come back here and tell me** the distinctions I made in my examples in the links above. Please do not repeat the questions. Thanks.

Comment: I read them and the only difference I see is that the  present perfect progressive is used when we describe an ongoing situation. The present perfect can refer to an ongoing action but when it is used with "for". Is that right? Do I understand correctly? You said my original sentences mean different things. What is the exact difference? Is it that the present perfect progressive unlike the present perfect emphasizes an ongoing action?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/284734/she-has-taught-english-for-five-years?noredirect=1#comment531839_284734

Comment: I have been looking for this thread. I have been told that the meaning is the same. That's what prompted me to ask if different native speakers have different opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. She has been studying English for two years.

This **emphasizes** studying **as an ongoing or uninterrupted activity up until the present time of speaking.** It is also true now unless otherwise specified.

2. She has studied English for two years. (She is still studying it now.)

The present perfect in this case **just tells us she started at some point in the past** and it is still true now. As far as we can tell, she is still studying it.

Compare that to:
She studied English for two years.

**Feel** the difference?

The meaning is NOT exactly the same. The emphasis is different.

That same difference exists without for:

- She's been playing the cello all afternoon.
- She's played the cello all afternoon.

Important: the afternoon is not over at the time of speaking. The first emphasizes the activity and the second tells us it started in the past and is still true (the afternoon is not yet over in both cases).

Comment: Yes, I feel the difference. But why did you say regarding this part: "She has studied English for two years." (She is not studying it now.)  But later you adeded that she is still studying.
The present perfect in this case just tells us she started at some point in the past and it is still true now. As far as we can tell, she is still studying it.

Comment: That was a mistake. I fixed it.

Comment: And what you have said about "studying" applies to "teaching". Right?  "She has been teaching English for two years" is focused on an ongoing activity. But "She has taught English for two years" means that she started teaching it and is still teaching it. In both cases the person is still teaching English. Is that right?

Comment: @AntoniaA It applies to any active (action) verb. In both cases, the activity continues. The difference is one emphasizes the activity and the other just lets you know it started in the past.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! When you said "She has been studying English for two years  This emphasizes studying as an ongoing or uninterrupted activity up until the present time of speaking. It is also true now unless otherwise specified" do you mean by "unless otherwise specified" that both tenses with "for" can mean that the action is no longer in progress?

Comment: As in "She has been teaching English/has taught English" before started teaching French". If this is the right context fir the situation you mentioned.

Comment: I understand your difficulty in understanding the perfect tenses. If you add a duration "I have been studying for two years" always means I am still studying. To me " I've studied for two years" also means I'm still studying. But it is possible to say something like "I have studied for two years" as an experience in the past, but I find that very confusing. So if you are not studying anymore, I would use past simple: "I studied for two years. "She taught English before she started teaching French".

Comment: @Anouk, "I have studied for 2 years." is never "an experience in the past". It means it started in the past at a moment that is not specified and true at the time of speaking.

Comment: @Lambie, what did you mean by "unless otherwise specified"? Could you please explain?

Comment: @Lambie Is it possible at all to use present perfect simple plus duration for a past action? For example: "they have studied for three weeks", can this be used when they have finished studying?

Comment: @anouk, You need to engrave this in your mind: At the TIME of speaking, x is true. That is one of the main ideas + if it is an action, it is most likely still occurring unless other specified. "They have studied French for three weeks BUT today they aren't.". "Well, sir, as of this morning, have studied French for three weeks". The idea is that there is no interruption because it is NOT about the past, it is about connection to the PRESENT.

Comment: On the day when I have stopped studying French while the day is still going I can say "I have studied French for three weeks" but in the evening I use past simple and say I studied English for three weeks" is that right?

Comment: Instead of present perfect I can also use "I have been studying French". I hope that's right too.

Comment: You can say : "I have studied/ been studying French for three weeks, but I don't like it, so I'm going to stop. Until this moment, you have studied/been studying.  "I have studied French for two hours today" ( said during the day), I studied French for two hours today" ( said in the evening).

Comment: @AntoniaA Not at all: I have studied French for three hours this morning (or month or year); The **morning is not over**. This month: The month is not over. This year: the year is not over. And I'd done with this. There is simply nothing left to say.